# Should I use a left aligned scroll bar?

Tags: scrolling, alignment, scrollbars

Usually, users expect scroll bars to be at the right side of the content they want to scroll. My page menu is located on the left side of the page however and is intended to be scrolled separately (navigations layout looks like roughly like [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20258/colors-to-use-with-black-background).

Can I risk putting my scroll bar left to the menu instead of right? It might make my page layout more balanced (one progress bar to the left, one to the right). I wonder if users would feel too unconfortable with it though so I went here.

Answer (score 8):

Though design and user experience is becoming more dynamic and flexible, some things still remain traditional, just like anywhere you see the diskette icon, you automatically know its the save button and you might struggle to get used to another icon for save.

Hence, I would suggest you leave the scroll bar to the right, the user (a lot of users) will definitely feel more comfortable with it there.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully put the scrollbar on left in multiple products, and users had no issues with it.

Scroll bars are there to hint that the content is scrollable (also answered [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/127968/are-scroll-bars-dead-in-2019)) and  to give a feedback for current scroll position, as users do scrolling with the mouse wheel or content drag in modern interfaces. The position of the scroll bar does not affect it's purpose, as for example, horizontal scrollbars.